# Variable is used before being assigned graphql

Tags: typescript, graphql, variable-assignment, svelte

I am a little lost here. I am trying to simply return some graphql data, namely the popularSearchTerms, and they do in fact exist as an array of strings.. The current project has many files. So far I am writing this and getting error "variable "searchScreenQuery is used before being assigned." If you need more information let me know.

Appmachine.ts

```
import type { OperationStore } from '@urql/svelte';
import type { SearchScreenQuery } from '@gql/schema';

let searchScreenQuery: OperationStore<SearchScreenQuery, object>;
let popularData = searchScreenQuery?.data?.visitor.video.popularSearchTerms;
console.log(popularData)
```

GRAPHQL FILE

```
query SearchScreen($query: String!) {
    visitor {
        video {
            popularSearchTerms
            search(query: $query) {
                nodes {
                    ...SearchResultCard_Video_VideoAssetInterface
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: The code you've posted cannot produce the error you quote. 1. `searchScreenQuery` is not used before being assigned. 2. `searchScreenQuery` is declared twice which would cause a *different* error.

Comment: I added a screenshot, you can se its underlined with that message I mentioned. I removed the second declaration, but first error remains

Comment: You need to give `searchScreenQuery` a value before you use it. Currently it's implicitly `undefined`.

Comment: You've never assigned a value to it, so it can only be `undefined`. What else do you expect? If you want a value, you need to assign one.

Comment: I see what your saying, but I think the issue lies elsewhere, if I write:  let searchScreenQuery = 'hello'; then yes its defined as "hello". but you can see I am attempting to access an object from a graphql search so I can't navigate to searchScreenQuery?.data? for instance...because data doesnt exist. I need to fetch the data, store it in a variable, and log it.